# How to only rewrite specific urls without affecting other files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite an url on a webshop so pages don't have file extensions and the url shows the category the product belongs to in the url.

I already fixed the category part, so my url now looks like this:

```
http://webshop.nl/douche/douche-2.html
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
http://webshop.nl/douche/douche-2
```

I tried the following line:

```
RewriteRule         ^(.*)/(.*) product-page.php?cat=$1&alias=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But this rewrites all files to product-page.php including css/js/html files. Can I somehow exclude those or only apply the line to products?

This is how I get the productinfo with the `alias` if it helps:

```
$artikel = '
SELECT cnt.id, cnt.title as content_title, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.state, cnt.introtext, cat.id, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 4 then f.value end) as prijs,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 5 then f.value end) as prijsoud,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 6 then f.value end) as specificaties
FROM snm_fields_values f
JOIN snm_content cnt
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cnt.catid = cat.id
WHERE cnt.alias = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['alias']).'"
AND cnt.state = 1
GROUP BY f.item_id';
$artikelcon = $conn->query($artikel);
$artikel = $artikelcon->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product-page.php?cat=$1&alias=$2 [QSA,L]
```

- `RewriteCond` make sure to rewrite it only for non-files and non-directories
- Better to use `[\w-]+` instead of `.*` in regex to avoid matching URLs with dot characters.

Comment: Thanks! This did the job. I can write multiple rules under the conditions? Because I want the same for my category listing page. - I can accept the answer in 5 minutes btw.

Comment: Yes you can use similar pattern to write category page also.